# Groovy - Storing output of a script to a variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline job with the following Groovy script.

```
  String max_month = 'psql -h host -U user db -t -c "SELECT MAX(month_id) FROM service_%s"'
  String query = String.format(max_month, params.QUART)
  sh query
```

How do I save the result returned by the query in a variable.

Comment: Use returnStdout param https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

Comment: `def result=sh(returnStdout: true, script: query).trim()`